# Hash Multi-Map Issues

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two questions on Java HashMap:

1) Is it possible in any implementation of Java HashMap to get corresponding Key from the value ? I am using HashMultiMap (key -) Multiple values).

2) Is it possible in any implementation of Java HashMap to get Key position in the HashMap ? If so, then If I add new key, is it possible that the key position is changed ? I am using HashMultiMap (key -) Multiple values).

If both of them answer is NOT, how is it possible to implement manually (any idea ?) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "position in the map"? A map is not indexable, so that doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I found in some web document, it is possible by using some other structure like HashMap, but not clearly. That's why, I asked.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by getting the position? Why do you *care*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Yes, but not in an efficient way, and there are no methods in interface `Map` to do this with one method call. You'd have to iterate over the entries of the map until you find one with the value you're looking for; then you have the key of the corresponding entry. There are implementation such as [Google Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `BiMap` that do let you do reverse lookups efficiently.

2) No, because a map is not an ordered collection: keys do not have a defined position in a map. If you need this, you could use for example `LinkedHashMap`, which keeps key-value pairs in the order they are inserted in the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, is it possible for HashMultiMap (key with Multiple values) also ?

Comment: I found here (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/google-guava-libraries-essentials.html) BitMap example with only key with Single value.  Is this possible for Key with Multiple value also ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no ready-made implementation in Guava that's both a `BiMap` and `Multimap`, so you'd have to write a lookup method yourself.

Comment: We haven't found much demand for `BiMultimap`, but on the other hand, `ImmutableSetMultimap` has an `inverse()` method that lets you construct the inverse mapping, like `BiMultimap` would.  On the other hand, it's an expensive operation, so if you need it, try to only call `inverse()` once and then do all the queries on the same multimap.